# jQuery dynamic id rearange

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get a straight id numeration for table rows.

For example if you have a table with 5 rows the row ids should be from 1 - 5.

But because i have a dynamic table where a row can be added or deleted the problem comes when a user deletes a row somewhere in the middle.

Let's say you add 3 new rows into table

```
row-1
row-2
row-3
```

and if you delete second row you will end up with

```
row-1
row-3
```

and if you add a new row (because I am getting the id from previous row) you will get this

```
row-1
row-3
row-4
```

How to come around this problem? How to rearange the row ids dynamically?

I think this has to be bind with row deletion because adding is not a problem if no rows were deleted in the middle.

Here is an example at [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ermz6d96/). inspect the id attributes in the web browser

Comment: Why do you want to re-arrange the ids?

Comment: Because I am using that variable to store data in my DB

Comment: Yea, so in that way, it is not recommended to re index your records, it might break your db when you have relational model

Comment: I am not indexing the records....it is a little more complicated because i can't show the code. (company rules). the problem is that i am not re indexing the data that gets into DB i just need it to be properly ordered with ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write the code to rearrange the ids of row from index 1. You can target rows from index 1 using gt selector along with `.attr()` callback function to set new ids:

```
$('#t1 tr:gt(0)').attr('id',function(i,o){
    return "r"+ i++ ;
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sdtd3kLf/)**

Comment: or just `i++`, sorry for being picky

Comment: @Mr.Alien: Thanks. your suggestion make sense. don't be sorry :)

Comment: what is `tr:gt(0)` i have never seen this before...i googled it it says greater than >

Comment: @lewis4u You can also do something like `$('#t1 tr:not(:eq(0))')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
var rows = $('#t1 tr') // get the amount of rows

$.each(rows, function(i, e) {
    $(e).attr("id", "r" + i);// set the new id
})
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '#addRow', function() {
  var row = parseInt($('#t1 tr:last-child').attr('id').replace(/[^\d]/g, ''), 10) + 1;
  $('#t1').append('<tr id="r' + row + '"><td><input name="item[]" type="text"/></td><td><input name="quantity[]" type="number"/></td><td><button class="deleteRow">X</button></td></tr>');

  var rows = $('#t1 tr')

  $.each(rows, function(i, e) {
    $(e).attr("id", "r" + i);
  })
});

$(document).on('click', '.deleteRow', function() {
  var row = parseInt($(this).closest('tr').attr('id').replace(/[^\d]/g, ''), 10);

  if (row > 1) {
    $('#r' + row).remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="t1">
  <tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="r1">
    <td>
      <input name="item[]" type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="quantity[]" type="number" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="deleteRow">X</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="addRow">Add Row</button>
```

Comment: this works also but Milind Anantwar was first to answer

Comment: No problem, just happy to help